# Angular toggle button or possibly another solution

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I am trying to make a button show and hide a div. I think I almost have it done, but I am missing this very last part.

Here is what I would like to happen: when you click on the red "change template" button, the text changes to "back to page 1". Now click on the red button again. The one that says "back to page 1" - I need that to actually change the div below to the yellow box. Right now it does nothing when you click on the red button the second time.

I would also need the text to change back to "change template". I am thinking what I need is a toggle button.

I have tried to implement multiple toggle buttons I found on stackoverflow already, but it seems my other code might be getting in the way. I made a plunker so its easy to see the problem.

http://plnkr.co/edit/RpqoXXHGBeYaBzIlD8Qb?p=preview

```
<div class="btn top-menu-button finchbutton red" ng-click="finchange='show';finpage1='';finpage2='';finpage3='';hellotext='hide';goodbyetext='show'">
<span class="btntext" ng-class="hellotext">Change Template</span><span class="btntext" ng-class="goodbyetext">Back To Template</span></div>
<div class="btn top-menu-button finbutton1 orange" ng-click="finpage1='show';finpage2='';finpage3='';finchange='';hellotext='show';goodbyetext='hide'">Page 1</div>
<div class="btn top-menu-button finbutton2 blue" ng-click="finpage2='show';finpage1='';finpage3='';finchange='';hellotext='show';goodbyetext='hide'">Page 2</div>
<div class="btn top-menu-button finbutton3 pink" ng-click="finpage3='show';finpage1='';finpage2='';finchange='';hellotext='show';goodbyetext='hide'">Page 3</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

As per your code, whenever you click on the button it will always hide "hellotext" and show "goodbyetext"

What you need to do is add is a function which checks for the value of hellotext and/or goodbyetext and toggle it based on values

Hope it helps!!

Answer (score 0):

If I get you right you need a toggle button behavior. This case it will be more naturally to use ng-show/ng-hide

```
<div ng-app="ngAnimate" ng-init="firstOn=true;">


  <div class="btn top-menu-button finchbutton red" ng-click="firstOn = !firstOn;">
    <span class="btntext" ng-show="firstOn">Change Template</span><span ng-hide="firstOn" class="btntext">Back To Page 1</span></div>
  <div class="btn top-menu-button finbutton1 orange" ng-click="">Page 1</div>
  <div class="btn top-menu-button finbutton2 blue" ng-click="">Page 2</div>
  <div class="btn top-menu-button finbutton3 pink" ng-click="">Page 3</div>

  <br>
  <span class="template-panel red" ng-show="!firstOn">Red</span>
  <span class="template-panel orange" ng-show="firstOn">Orange</span>
  <span class="template-panel blue hide">Blue</span>
  <span class="template-panel pink hide">Pink</span>

</div>
```

You can see the example (I simplified yours a little to have the idea clear) at http://plnkr.co/edit/es5pgmrgsXbm6bP8CSrr

Comment: Thanks! It seems to work, but then when I add in all of my code, the red div disappears completely when I toggle the button. It also seems that the "page 1" button doesn't really work if the red button is in it's toggled state. I'm going to keep working on it...Thanks again.

Comment: Your css provides opacity:0 to all .template-panel. It might be a reason why you have nothing visible in your code